# Как в Laravel выводить контент из контроллера, если вызывается другой контроллер

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

Начал изучать Laravel (8 версия).
Допустим, есть двухколоночный сайт. В левом блоке постоянно на всех страницах выводится из базы данных или по результатам работы какого-то метода какого-то контроллера какой-то контент.
Далее, создаю контроллер, который будет работать по определенному маршруту с основной частью контента сайта (условно, правый блок). Не могу понять, если в маршруте я вызываю тот метод контроллера, который отвечает за вывод контента в правый блок, то каким образом должен тогда наполняться левый блок? Каким образом вызвать метод контроллера, отвечающий за контент левого блока, который выводится всегда на всех страницах?
В шаблоне blade на левый блок сайта стоят @yiled'ы, которые прописаны в @section других шаблонов, но как значение переменных из метода контроллера (который не вызывается из маршрута) попадет в переменные, стоящие в @section, отвечающие за левый блок сайта?
Я даже в гугл запрос не могу нормально составить, чтобы получить ответ.

Comment: или асинхронная загрузка (js), или вы не так себе представляете разделение в MVC.

Comment: Для одного запроса - один контроллер. Иного не дано. Максимум - один контроллер модифицирует запрос и вызывает другой, но это для другой цели. Хотите два блока - значит нужны две переменные, для левого и правого блока, обе из которых можно наполнить в одном контроллере и далее вызвать шаблон.

Answer (score 2):

Кроме контроллеров, существуют и другие понятия, а также сущности в Laravel.

То что вы хотите сделать, можно через View Composers: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers

Если вам нужно модифицировать результат этого блока в зависимости от страницы, вы можете использовать экземпляр Request.

Также вы можете передавать значение через расшаривание переменных в представлении: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Или же вы можете использовать инъекции: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#service-injection

Но если результаты блоков привязаны к URL или какой-то сущности, то лучше передавать данные через контроллер и вызов view(), а при отсутствии данных вы можете использовать другое представление (компонент, данные). Это можно сделать с помощью расширения представлений, условий в Blade и даже условий в контроллере.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте достать ваш контроллер как сервис из контейра и вызвать нужную функцию.
например где-то в шаблоне:

```
{{ app(OtherController::class)->renderSidebar() }};
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно использовать метод `callAction()` класса `Controller`. Вот инструкция подробнее https://hccoder.info/category/laravel/post-1139 и с готовым примером.

Comment: лучше приложить (нажав [edit]) краткое изложение того, что написано по ссылке. потому что если ссылка перестанет работать, ваш ответ потеряет смысл.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/847720)